# How is the popularity of "recent tags" calculated?

Tags: discussion, support, recent-tags

[image: Recent tags image]

How are these calculated? I see them going up and down all the time, and there are obviously way more than 48 questions about C# so how are these calculated?

Comment: I'd assume within the last hour is how it's calculated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's basically looking at recently:

- created
- positively scored

And then tossing out any tags that don't occur at least a minimum number of times in the whole database.  A tag has to have some traction (ie. be a real tag people really use) to get into that list.

The exact numbers vary a bit site to site, but that's the gist of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but I went to the newest tab, and counted how far the questions go, and here are the results (sorted by number of questions):

1. Apache........x 4 - 2 hours
2. git................x 10 - 3 hours
3. C++.............x 34 - 3 hours
4. Java............x 48 - 2 hours
5. Javascript...x 50 - 3 hours
6. PHP............x 69- 3 hours
7. C#...............x 76- 4 hours